# Is it possible to reduce functional equations to SAT?

Tags: algorithms, reductions, satisfiability, lambda-calculus, functional-programming

The problem of finding a solution for functional equations can be defined as:

> Let $A_0, A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n, B_0, B_1, B_2, \dots, B_n, X$ be terms of the $\lambda$-calculus, where all terms are known except for $X$. Given a set of $N$ equations in the form $X A_n \to B_n$ (that is, $X$ applied to $A_n$ strongly normalizes to $B_n$), what is an algorithm that finds $X$ for arbitrary $A, B$?

Since there is no published solution for this problem on literature (as far as I known), is there any way to reduce that problem to SAT?

Comment: This sounds like a 'program synthesis' problem, for the lambda calculus. I suggest that you search the research literature on that problem -- there's a ton of published work on it.  Reducing to SAT is a typical approach to program synthesis problems.  You basically need to find someone who has designed a system for program synthesis for the lambda calculus.

Comment: SAT can indeed be used to "solve" (find the solution to) arbitrary equations/ functions to arbitrary precision, but the precision must be specified in advance (it corresponds to # of bits in solution). it would help if you defined "strongly normalize" and cite this in the literature if it came from somewhere. do not know of a ref that proves this. possibly drop by [chat] for further analysis.

Comment: as for refs, this is nearly an application of the [Cook-Levin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem) theorem.

Comment: This is a higher-order unification problem, there are *tons* of published approaches for this problem!

Comment: @cody a few years later, but yes! I'm still very interested in this problem haha. If you have any specifically good resource or paper you'd like to share, feel free to :)